# Cloning a submodule using a CI Runner

Tags: python, git-submodules, gitlab-ci-runner

So I have my .gitlab-ci.yml file as follows:

```
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: fetch
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
```

and in my .gitmodules my submodule that I want to clone too:

```
[submodule "src/submodule"]
    path = src/submodule
    url = https://gitlab.company.com/submodule/submodule.git
```

Now, when I clone the whole repository locally, everything works out fine, the submodule is cloned too. However a CI runner, gives the follow error:

```
Cloning into '/builds/user/CITest/src/submodule'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab.company.com': No such device or address
fatal: clone of 'https://gitlab.company.com/submodule/submodule.git' into submodule path '/builds/user/CITest/src/submodule' failed
Failed to clone 'src/submodule'. Retry scheduled
```

I tried by giving the runner a secure token, as well as trying to set secret variables, although I am not a hundred percent sure I am using them correctly. I found a lot of errors that are similar, but they are mostly concerned with calling the submodule as a job, here I need to fetch it straight away.

Also as a note, I do have access to the submodule normally, since also the cloning locally works perfectly fine.

Do I maybe need to set up a runner manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use relative URLs for your submodules which are located in the same GitLab server.

For example:

```
[submodule "src/submodule"]
    path = src/submodule
    url = ../../group/submodule.git
```

Other submodules not located on the same GitLab server, you can use the normal full HTTPS protocol URL.

[Relevant documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html#configuring-the-gitmodules-file).

Comment: Thanks a lot already for the quick answer! So that is what I did before, which worked perfectly well, but I was wondering if there is no way around this, to make it work on the same GitLab server AND on another server. Since in this way, somebody using the submodule from another server would have to change the yml file.

Comment: What's the error you get on the other (GitLab?) server?

Comment: Well at the moment it is more of a hypothetical question, since I don't use it from the other GitLab server. I was wondering basically if its possible to write one bit which would work for both. Or do you have to change the yml file depending if you're on the same or on a different server?

Comment: Hmm, I suppose it depends how you have it setup. If you're mirroring this repository (and have the relative links to the submodules) to another GitLab server, if you also mirror the submodules (to the same location), the build should still work, as it's grabbing it from the same relative path on the other server.

Comment: Ok perfect. I noticed that actually this question is a bit of a non-issue just now, but I was wondering about this. Thank you a lot!